# How to get all lines in a log file containing either PASSED or FAILED written into a new file using FINDSTR?

Tags: batch-file, variables, findstr

I want to find the words `passed` **or** `failed` in a log file and save the lines where the match succeeded in an output file. I wrote a small batch script using the `findstr` command. It does not seem to work.

1. It doesn't work when I used the variables in the `if exist` condition which is strange.
2. The `findstr` command  returns nothing.

I'm a beginner in batch programming so maybe I miss-understood some notions in batch.

```
@echo off
set Input = simulation_results.log
set Output = sim_catchedmsg.log
if exist %Output% del %Output%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%Input%) do (
  Set line=%%a 
  findstr /X "passed failed" %line% >> %Output%
  pause)
```

**Input log file:**

```
<time="1500 ns" instance="testcase_00">passed
<time="342100480 ps" instance="testcase_01">passed
blabla informations about the tests....
<time="742894 ns" instance="testcase_02_01">passed
blabla informations about the tests....
blabla informations about the tests....
<time="744121040 ps" instance="testcase_02_02">failed
blabla informations about the tests....
<time="745034560 ps" instance="testcase_02_03">passed
blabla informations about the tests....
<time="745134560 ps" instance="testcase_02_04">passed
blabla informations about the tests....
blabla informations about the tests....
blabla informations about the tests....
blabla informations about the tests....
<time="745548080 ps" instance="testcase_03">failed
<time="747388640 ps" instance="testcase_04_01">passed
<time="750745100 ns" instance="testcase_04_02">passed
blabla informations about the tests....
```

Comment: If you want to use `findstr` with an `OR` condition, you might have a look at this post "https://serverfault.com/questions/123483/doing-logical-or-comparisons-with-findstr-exe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with your code.

1) Do not put spaces on either side of the equal symbol in a `SET` command.

2) You are using the `FINDSTR` command incorrectly.  The `line` variable is not a file.  The `FINDSTR` command expects the last argument to be the name of a file.

3) You have delayed expansion problem if you really want to do the `FINDSTR` inside the `FOR` command.

All you need to do is this.

```
@echo off
set "Input=simulation_results.log"
set "Output=sim_catchedmsg.log"
if exist "%Output%" del "%Output%"
findstr "passed failed" "%input%">>"%Output%"
```